# Profile backup script for XP migrate to Vista

Tags: backup, windows-command-prompt, profile

I have a .cmd i use to copy our users local files when they change computer. This works very well in XP/2000 but now i can see that we (large enterprise) are moving to Vista. And was wondering if the paths used in my .cmd would work on Vista too...

this is a real cut and paste from the script ("to short down my post" if the full script is needed/wanted i can insert that...) just to show the paths:

```
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Desktop "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Favorites" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\My Documents" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Start Menu" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Local Settings\Application Data\other" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\%Process%" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Application Data\Microsoft\Address Book" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Application Data\Microsoft\Proof" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
robocopy "C:\DOCUME~1\%userid%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook" "%dest%\%Process%" /S /E /COPYALL /V /NP /NJH /LOG+:"%logfile%" /R:10 /W:15 /TEE
```

set dest=x:\%userid% and %process% is the part after  %userid%

Comment: Holy Crap! Ever thought about deploying Roaming profiles, with UPHClean and such so you don' thave to worry about registry locks and always win?

Comment: I really wish i could, but this is not an option for me. It's a very standarized and controlled environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the environmental variable %USERPROFILE% to access current user's profile.

And that variable is universal and works on all Windows versions from Win95 to Win7.

On default install of XP it would give you c:\document and settings\username
on Vista it would give you c:\users\username

Answer (score 2):

If your question is: *"Has the structure of the Users folder changed in Vista?"* then the answer is: *"yes"*.

Your best bet is to use [USMT (The User State Migration Tool)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722032(WS.10).aspx)

Our corporation migrated almost 10,000 workstations/users to Vista this way.

Comment: This is something we have a specialized version of that is not suitable for us in our region right now, but were working on it.